# How can I normalize Hedges' g from two extreme conditions around the control condition?

Tags: meta-analysis, normalization, effect-size, cohens-d

The variables I am discussing below are not the ones I am actually using but I think that they should give a better sense of what I am trying achieve.

I am performing a meta-analysis of some chosen factors on subjective wellbeing. Let's say, I would like to focus on how subjective wellbeing is affected by positive vs negative relationships with people (effect size between two extreme conditions) and whether one suffers from some medical illness (effect size between a control group and some condition). For that reason, I would like to compute effect sizes for both of these factors and give it in Hedges' g. Afterwards, I would like to include these effect sizes to see how their combinations affect subjective wellbeing.

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to add effect sizes (Hedges' g), assuming that they are properly normalized/standardized?;
2. Is it possible to: a) *estimate the effect size of positive relationships with people compared with the control group*; and b) *to estimate the effect size of negative relationships with people vs the control group* given that I know the effect size for positive vs negative relationships with people?

For the 2), assume that my data is normally distributed and that I was able to ensure that my measurement of negative and positive relationships really reflected the most extreme cases (which is measurable by quantiles). Also, it can be assumed that neutral relationships with people are associated with neutral subjective wellbeing.

I apologize if you find my question a bit convoluted.

I would be extremely grateful for any help!